# Public Keys to decode Azure AD (all microsoft accounts) Access tokens

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt

I am trying to decode the Access tokens and ID tokens generated by Azure Active Directory.

I have been successful with the single tenant apps, but when in process of decoding this type of app:
**Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**

I cannot find the public key corresponding to the "kid" I receive in the jwt header.

I have tried searching through the following discovery urls:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/keys
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/keys?appid={client_id}
```

Please help me with the discovery url or the public key to use for these type of apps where the user can use any microsoft user account to sign in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with these discovery urls

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/v2.0/keys

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys 

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/discovery/v2.0/keys?appid={appid}
```

Reference: [Joonas W's blog](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-v2-and-msal-in-2020#:%7E:text=To%20recap%2C%20the%20v2%20endpoint%20allows%20%22converged%20authentication%22%2C,endpoint%20only%20allows%20authentication%20with%20Azure%20AD%20accounts.) says

*The **v2 endpoint** allows "converged authentication", i.e. users can use either their organizational Office 365 (Azure AD) accounts or their personal Microsoft Accounts (e.g. outlook.com). In contrast, the v1 endpoint only allows authentication with Azure AD accounts.*